# How to adjust Partition Scheme Wemos D1 mini pro?

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, flash, memory

I bought myself a WEMOS D1 mini PRO (16MB) for creating a quite large project.

As I'm writing code, my memory is starting to grow.
When I looked at the Flash size in Arduino IDE, the only options I have are

- FS 14MB, OTA: 1019KB
- FS 15MB, OTA: 512KB

The only things I need in the project is OTA and EEPROM. (no need for SPIFFS)

I looked around on the internet and came on a couple of sites that manipulate the filesystem.
https://robotzero.one/arduino-ide-partitions/

Also on other forums I read that you could modify the LD scripts that Arduino uses.
But I'm not sure how to define the addresses and what to do.

Here is a visual of the config I want.

**ORIGINAL**

[image]

**ADJUSTED**

[image]

Can someone push me into the right direction ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the maximum size of application code on esp8266 is 1MB

Comment: I know but it is possible to adjust the 1 MB. But I don't know how to adjust the addresses.

Comment: adjust how? 1 MB is the limit of the CPU on addressing instructions. why is your code so big? put large strings or data in FS files.

Comment: @JensVanhulst What Juraj is saying is that the CPU cannot cope with any more than 1MB. Regardless of the size of the flash. That is why there are no settings where the code size is more than 1MB - it's the absolute maximum that you can have. No amount of fiddling with config files can change that, it's a physical property of the chip.